# Cannot cast generated Avro class to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord

Tags: java, gradle, avro, gradle-plugin

I'm using [commercehub-oss](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-avro-plugin) gradle plugin to generate Java classes by Avro protocol.

Here's my .avdl file:

```
@namespace("com.abc.xyz")
protocol XYZ_Protocol_v1 {
  record VendorItemInfo {
      string vendorItemId;
      long price;
      string deliveryChargeType;
  }

  record XyzDto {
    array<VendorItemInfo> vendorItemInfos;
  }
}
```

Based on commercehub-oss [wiki](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-avro-plugin), I ran $gradle build to generate the java files based on my .avdl file.

Then when I made a request to my service, I got this error stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.xyz.domain.dto.VendorItemInfo cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:666)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:681)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:151)
    org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:90)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:143)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:105)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeArray(GenericDatumWriter.java:179)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:107)
    org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:87)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:143)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:105)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:60)
```

Any ideas how to fix this please?